# Why is strconv.ParseUint so slow compared to strconv.Atoi?

Tags: performance, go, type-conversion, benchmarking, microbenchmark

I'm benchmarking unmarshaling from `string` to `int` and `uint` with this code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "strconv"
    "testing"
)

func BenchmarkUnmarshalInt(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        UnmarshalInt("123456")
    }
}

func BenchmarkUnmarshalUint(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        UnmarshalUint("123456")
    }
}

func UnmarshalInt(v string) int {
    i, _ := strconv.Atoi(v)
    return i
}

func UnmarshalUint(v string) uint {
    i, _ := strconv.ParseUint(v, 10, 64)
    return uint(i)
}
```

Result:

```
Running tool: C:\Go\bin\go.exe test -benchmem -run=^$ myBench/main -bench .

goos: windows
goarch: amd64
pkg: myBench/main
BenchmarkUnmarshalInt-8     99994166            11.7 ns/op         0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkUnmarshalUint-8    54550413            21.0 ns/op         0 B/op          0 allocs/op
```

Is it possible that the second (`uint`) is almost twice as slow as the first (`int`)?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's possible. `strconv.Atoi` has a fast path when the input string length is less than 19 (or 10 if `int` is 32 bit). This allows it to be a lot faster because it doesn't need to check for overflow.

If you change your test number to "1234567890123456789" (assuming 64 bit int), then your int benchmark is slightly slower than the uint benchmark because the fast path can't be used. On my machine, it takes 37.6 ns/op for the signed version vs 31.5 ns/op for the unsigned version.

Here's the modified benchmark code (note I added a variable that sums up the parsed results, just in case the compiler got clever and optimized it away).

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "strconv"
        "testing"
)

const X = "1234567890123456789"

func BenchmarkUnmarshalInt(b *testing.B) {
        var T int
        for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
                T += UnmarshalInt(X)
        }
        fmt.Println(T)
}

func BenchmarkUnmarshalUint(b *testing.B) {
        var T uint
        for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
                T += UnmarshalUint(X)
        }
        fmt.Println(T)
}

func UnmarshalInt(v string) int {
        i, _ := strconv.Atoi(v)
        return i
}

func UnmarshalUint(v string) uint {
        i, _ := strconv.ParseUint(v, 10, 64)
        return uint(i)
}
```

For reference, the code for [`strconv.Atoi`](https://golang.org/src/strconv/atoi.go?s=5658:5690#L214) in the standard library is currently as follows:

```
func Atoi(s string) (int, error) {
    const fnAtoi = "Atoi"

    sLen := len(s)
    if intSize == 32 && (0 < sLen && sLen < 10) ||
        intSize == 64 && (0 < sLen && sLen < 19) {
        // Fast path for small integers that fit int type.
        s0 := s
        if s[0] == '-' || s[0] == '+' {
            s = s[1:]
            if len(s) < 1 {
                return 0, &NumError{fnAtoi, s0, ErrSyntax}
            }
        }

        n := 0
        for _, ch := range []byte(s) {
            ch -= '0'
            if ch > 9 {
                return 0, &NumError{fnAtoi, s0, ErrSyntax}
            }
            n = n*10 + int(ch)
        }
        if s0[0] == '-' {
            n = -n
        }
        return n, nil
    }

    // Slow path for invalid, big, or underscored integers.
    i64, err := ParseInt(s, 10, 0)
    if nerr, ok := err.(*NumError); ok {
        nerr.Func = fnAtoi
    }
    return int(i64), err
}
```

Comment: Oh. Thanks a lot. I am deciding whether to use `int` or `uint` for the model IDs of my project. IDs will be marshaled and unmarshaled several times by the JSON/GraphQL adapters and so if I have them under 19 characters it will definitely be much faster. Am I right? What do you suggest? Gorm 2's new approach is to use `uint`s for IDs.

Comment: 10 nanoseconds is not going to make any difference in your overall unmarshaling time.

Comment: What do you suggest for IDs? `int` or `uint`, @Jimb?

Comment: Better to benchmark and profile the full application before microoptimising this detail. If marshalling IDs is a bottleneck then consider switching between uint or int.

Comment: @PaulHankin Ok, but I'm in the modeling stage and I'm trying to figure out what's best. If I can avoid this at this stage it is better, right?

Comment: It literally does not matter. If these are opaque identifiers which are not going to used for any calculations, then uint is fine.

Comment: Use `uint64` because they are fixed size, and in general you don't need negative ids.

Comment: They are NOT opaque IDs. They are visible and everytime marshaled and unmarshaled from JSON on each request. This is my doubt.